# Openerp_ Magento Integration/sync Error

Tags: magento, odoo, erp

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/connector/queue/worker.py",     line 123, in run_job
job.perform(session)
   File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/connector/queue/job.py", line 492, in perform
     self.result = self.func(session, *self.args, **self.kwargs)
   File    "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/magentoerpconnect/unit/import_synchronizer.py", line 378, in import_record
importer.run(magento_id, force=force)
 File        "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/magentoerpconnect/unit/import_synchroni zer.py", line 221, in run
      self._import_dependencies()
   File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/magentoerpconnect/sale.py", line 849, in _import_dependencies
'magento.product.product')
   File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/magentoerpconnect/unit/import_synchronizer.py", line 124, in _import_dependency
importer.run(magento_id)
   File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/magentoerpconnect/unit/import_synchronizer.py", line 206, in run
    self.magento_record = self._get_magento_data()
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/magentoerpconnect/unit/import_synchronizer.py", line 63, in _get_magento_data
    return self.backend_adapter.read(self.magento_id)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/magentoerpconnect/product.py", line 278, in read
[int(id), storeview_id, attributes, 'id'])
     File    "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/magentoerpconnect/product.py", line 243, in _call
   return super(ProductProductAdapter, self)._call(method, arguments)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/magentoerpconnect/unit/backend_adapter.py", line 168, in _call
 result = api.call(method, arguments)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/magento-0.4-py2.7.egg/magento/api.py", line 161, in call
return self.client.call(self.session, resource_path, arguments)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1578, in __request
verbose=self.__verbose
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1297, in single_request
  return self.parse_response(response)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1473, in parse_response
   return u.close()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 793, in close
   raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
 Fault: <Fault 3: 'Invalid api path.'>
```

I Am Unable To Integrated & Sync My Products From Magento To Openerp,I Have Used The CampToCamp's Add-on In The Openerp & Have Added The Module On Magento. I Have Used My Magento Server Link & Have Added Enough Test Products Yet The Products Aren't Syncing Due To The Above error As In The Jobs Tab In Openerp. Please Help Me Get Through Or Understand What Am I Doing Wrongly.
Thank You In Advance.

Comment: Please don't upload an image of an error. It's not searchable and downright annoying. Also (but less important) why are there no line breaks in your question and why is every word starting with a capital?

Comment: Oh i'm sorry about it the line breaks that is & the error is the last line Fault: <Fault 3: "Invalid api" >

Comment: @OmiHarjani Have you solve this? I have same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the integration module which was installed on my magento site didn't match the integration module on Openerp so all i needed to do was install both from the same vender and it worked like a charm.
Just remove both the integration modules from openerp & magento,& follow a single vender for me i used the following guide to get the Integration working.

https://openerp-magento-connector.readthedocs.org/en/develop/index.html